# Cannot open Excel generated using poi-3.0-alpha1-20050704.jar

Tags: java, apache-poi

I coded a simple method to generate an Excel workbook. The file generated may be opened using OpenOffice but Excel2007 does not recognizes it, crashing and forcing to restart Excel.

I also have poi-scratchpad-3.0-alpha1-20050704.jar in classpath.

The code is as simple as:

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
.
.
.
workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
sheet = workbook.createSheet();
row = sheet.createRow(currentRow);
cell = row.createCell(HEADER1_COLUMN);
cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
cell.setCellValue(HEADER_TEXT);
```

Is there any problem using given version or may I code something different?

Comment: are you calling workbook.write() in the end?

Comment: yes, I write the content at the end, but not included in the post to make it easy to understand.Thanks

Comment: i tried your code. it worked for me. But I have poi-3.2-FINAL-20081019.jar. You could try updating your jar to the latest and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks Ashwini, but I'd like to make it run on 3.0-alpha1-20050704 version 'cause it's not easy to upgrade the project to a newer version (there are lot of functional dependencies)

Comment: You are aware that 3.0 alpha 1 is almost 7 years old, aren't you? There has been [an amazingly huge number of bug fixes](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html) since then!

Comment: Functional dependencies with an alpha version? Not good

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be running a 6.5 year old alpha version of POI! That's, well, "unusual"....

If you take a look at the [POI change log and bug fix list](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html), you'll see that in the intervening 6.5 years, there have been so many bug fixes that you'll need to scroll through about 20 pages to see a summary of them all!

You should upgrade to a much much newer version, and almost certainly all your problems will go away. If you can, upgrade to the most recent 3.8 beta, then upgrade again in a few weeks when 3.8 final is out. If not, upgrade to 3.7 final, but there's been [quite a few bug fixes](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html) since then that are in the 3.8 betas, so going for 3.8 is to be recommended.